# want to display sale price below regular price in woocommerce single product page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

want to display sale price below regular price in woocommerce single product page. And also want to show regular price font small then sale price. I try to find it in many ways and also implement many code but it didn't work. Please suggest me,

Comment: Posting specific code examples or links to your work will help users give feedback. The arrangement and style of your page depend on the code you're working with – and this question doesn't provide enough information to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

For displaying the sale price, you could do something like below.

```
$original_price = 500 //Whatever your price is
$sale_percentage = 10 
$sale_price = (sale_percentage/10)*original_price
echo "Sale price: " . $sale_price
```

Insert that into your WordPress site and there are some links on how to do that over [here](https://www.hostinger.co.uk/tutorials/wordpress/how-to-add-php-code-to-wordpress-post-or-page).

To change the font smaller or bigger, visit this [link](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-change-the-font-size-in-wordpress/) which will tell you how to do this.

Comment: want to display both price Like below
 Regular Price : $130
 Sale price : $110

Comment: Yes the code above wouldn't change the regular price, it wold just display the Sale Price and I edited it to say "Sale Price: $x"

Comment: I think you didn't get my point, I want to show both price on single product page of WooCommerce. Where Regular price is above sale price. same like Amazon.com - https://www.amazon.com/Thermaltake-LEVEL-White-Gaming-Computer/dp/B007LB07HM/ref=sr_1_22?fst=as%3Aoff&pf_rd_i=16225007011&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=74069509-93ef-4a3c-8dca-a9e3fa773a64&pf_rd_r=468GJF6CWKX85WGSS031&pf_rd_s=merchandised-search-4&pf_rd_t=101&qid=1585079547&rnid=16225007011&s=computers-intl-ship&sr=1-22

However here there are list price then deal price. Same like this but regular price and sale price.